# How to Install python3.4.3 with Ansible

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, python-3.4, pyenv

I want to install python3.x by use pyenv with ansible.

```
- name: install pyenv
  git: >
    repo=https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git
    dest=/home/www/.pyenv
    accept_hostkey=yes
    become: yes
    become_user: www

- name: enable pyenv
  shell: |
    echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="/home/www/.pyenv"' >> /home/www/.bashrc
    echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> /home/www/.bashrc
    echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> /home/www/.bashrc
- name: install python
  shell: pyenv install 3.4.3
```

How to install python3.x with ansible?

Comment: does that not work? what error messages do you get?

Comment: @tedder42 error message is "pyenv: not found". I think ansible can't read environment variable. maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using the `shell` module to set environment variables on the remote host, Ansible has the `environment` keyword, which can set per task or even per playbook.

Assuming the **`www` user already exists** I managed to get this working with some more specific path setting:

```
- name: enable pyenv and install python
  shell: /home/www/.pyenv/bin/pyenv init - && /home/www/.pyenv/bin/pyenv install 3.4.3 chdir=/home/www
  environment:
    pyenv_root: /home/www/.pyenv
    path: "{{ pyenv_root }}/bin:$PATH"
  become: yes
  become_user: www
```

You will need to run the playbook with:

```
ansible-playbook --ask-become-pass <playbook-name>
```

and supply the password for the `www` user on request.

If that doesn't work, you might have to post the whole playbook here for us to look at :)

Comment: thank you for help. I tried. but, still can't working.    `stderr: /bin/sh: 1: pyenv: not found `

Comment: sorry, I wrong something. error is `stderr: /usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory`

Comment: You mean OS? It's running on ubuntu.

Comment: @Hiro3 Updated my answer.

Answer (score 7):

So here is what worked for me well to get any version of python installed with ansible and make it an alternative installation. I first ran `configure` and `make`, later compressed the result since this takes a while, then re-distributed the file using a mirror so I can run `make altinstall` on its own. Here is the recipe:

```
---
# Check the alt python3 version
- name: check alt python version
  shell: /usr/local/bin/python3.6 --version
  register: python3_version
  ignore_errors: yes  # If not installed
  tags:
    - python-alt

# Stuff I did manually to compile everything first by hand
# Python3 alt-install - steps to create binary:
# wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.4/Python-3.6.4.tgz
# tar xf Python-3.6.4.tgz
# mv Python-3.6.4 Python-3.6.4-binary && cd Python-3.6.4-binary
# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-optimizations
# cd .. && tar -zcvf Python-3.6.4-binary.tar.gz Python-3.6.4-binary (upload to mirror servers)
# make && sudo make altinstall UNINST=1
- name: download and unpack alternative python3
  unarchive:
    src: http://www.yourmirror.com/centos/python/Python-3.6.4-binary.tar.gz dest=/tmp/Python-3.6.4-binary.tar.gz
    dest: /tmp
    remote_src: yes
    keep_newer: yes
  when: python3_version['stderr'] != 'Python 3.6.4'
  tags:
    - python-alt

# Its possible to install (instead of altinstall) python3 here
- name: make install alt python3
  make:
    chdir: /tmp/Python-3.6.4-binary
    target: altinstall
    params:
      UNINST: 1  # Replace
  when: python3_version['stderr'] != 'Python 3.6.4'
  become: yes
  tags:
    - python-alt

- name: download get-pip.py
  get_url:
    url: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
    dest: /tmp/get-pip.py
    mode: 0664
  tags:
    - python-alt

- name: install pip for python3
  shell: /usr/local/bin/python3.6 /tmp/get-pip.py
  become: yes
  tags:
    - python-alt

# We need virtualenv installed under py3 for the virtualenv command to work
- pip:
    name: virtualenv
    executable: /usr/local/bin/pip3.6
  become: True
  tags:
    - python-alt
```

If you want to compile everything on your server you could do the following before the `altinstall` step and also download the source code package instead of the pre-compiled tar. I don't recommend doing it this way because it does take up resources and you don't want to be doing it in prod. Using Python2.7.14 as an example:

```
---
# Build the default target
- debug:
    var: python2_version
  tags:
    - python_alt
- make:
    chdir: /tmp/Python-2.7.14-binary
  when: python2_version['stderr'] != 'Python 2.7.14'
  tags:
    - python_alt
- name: configure target command
  command: ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-optimizations chdir=/tmp/Python-2.7.14-binary
  when: python2_version['stderr'] != alt_python_version
  tags:
    - python_alt
```